# Error al ejecutar ng serve -o

Tags: angular

Hola intento ejecutar ng serve -o ,para poder abrir la app en LocalHost 4200, pero me arroja "Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace."

Intento hacerlo desde la terminal de Visual studio Code, inicialmente ejecute ng new "nombreDelProyecto", me crea todos los archivos de angular, pero me arroja varias warning y luego que no reconoce el mail y el usuario, me hace correr git.config user.email y user.name, luego cuando trato de ejecutar ng serve -o, me salta el error antes mencionado.

Comment: Tienes que colocarte dentro del directorio para ejecutar ese comando. `cd nombreDelProyecto`

Comment: Tal cual, muchas gracias